# How can I disable guardian in my passthrough Meta Quest application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I cannot seem to be able to disable the guardian in-app even though applications like first encounters do not have a guardian. Isn't it counterintuitive to not allow guardians to be turned off in passthrough mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Add the following to AndroidManifest.XML

```
<uses-feature android:name="com.oculus.feature.CONTEXTUAL_BOUNDARYLESS_APP" android:required="true" />
```